# Accessing Telerik RadGrid edit mode from javascript

Tags: javascript, telerik, telerik-grid, radgrid, radgridview

I invoke one function in javascript. When I call this function rad grid row is already in **edit mode**. In that function I get reference to RadGrid:

```
var masterTable = $find("<%= RadGrid1.ClientID %>").get_masterTableView();
```

In edit mode I have edit item:

I have a problem here to get/set value of txtName from this javascript function.
I have tried:

```
var item = masterTable.selectItem(masterTable.get_dataItems()[0].get_element());
var item = masterTable.selectItem('txtName');
var item = masterTable.selectItem('txtName').Text;
var item = masterTable.selectItem('txtName').value;
var item = masterTable.selectItem(3)
```

In all cases item is undefined. Any idea what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Are you able to find the grid before moving on to the master table view?  That is, if you do `var grid = $find('<%= RadGrid1.ClientID %>');`, do you get a defined object?

Comment: Yes when I try to find grid I got reference to it. I just can't get values out of edit item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could try this bit of jQuery to find it:

```
var item = $telerik.$(masterTable.get_element()).find('input[id*="txtName"]')[0];
```

some details on Telerik Jquery: http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/introduction-using-jquery.html